# A view jumps on top after a clicking on a button

Tags: ios, swift, uiwindow

My setup is a UITabBarController with two ViewControllers connected.
[setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2zNOg.png)

On one of the ViewControllers I've added a ContainerView constrained to the tab bar with a Blue Subview and a button on a subview. Constraints are here
[constraints](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uc4GB.png)

Then I add the containerView to keyWindow to show it on top of other ViewControllers like this:

```
        containerView!.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.addSubview(containerView!)
```

After adding the containerView to the keyWindow I press the button on a Blue view and the view jumps on top of the screen. What am I missing here?

What button does:

```
        @IBAction func changeColor(_ sender: Any) {
       blueView.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray
        }
```

NOTES: If I set a button picture to project asset and not system asset the view doesn't jump on top. [assets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kObpo.png)
Also, if I don't add the view to the keyWindow the view doesn't jump on top with whatever asset.

Answer (score 0):

In here like I see you use autolayout for constraint. So you need to remove         translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints to get the contsraints working.

So you need to remove this line

```swift
// remove this
// containerView!.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```